# iframe button redirect when clicked

Tags: html, iframe

I've made a fullscreen iframe for my login for my site because I can't access the source code for it, I want it to redirect to another page when the user presses the login button, is this possible and how would I do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
<iframe src="https://example.com" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>

</style>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the code. Please.

Comment: Sorry, just added it now.

Comment: I'm sorry. I actually want the source code of the https://example.com page. Please.

Answer (score 0):

I think this'll work. But if you give me the code, I will edit this answer and make it better for your use.

```
<form action="page.html">
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="password" name="password">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This code will redirect the page to page.html when the user clicks on the button.